# How can I declare an object in a class, that needs another in its constructor?

Tags: c++

I want to declare two objects from two different classes inside my private section of my class. The problem I have is that the second object should take the first object in a constructor. So here is the example of my class private section:

```
class FactorGraph
{
private:
    gtsam::ISAM2Params _parameters();
    gtsam::ISAM2 _isam(_parameters);
```

The _parameters object should be passed as an argument for the _isam object but from my knowledge that will not be possible as C++ does not allow this. Is there a slick way to do so?

Comment: Initialize them in your class's constructor.

Comment: @drescherjm Will they simply become private members when I initialize them?

Comment: You put them in the private section. So they are private.

Comment: `gtsam::ISAM2Params _parameters();` is not a member object, it is a member function, which takes no arguments and returns a `gtsam::ISAM2Params`.

Comment: You may want to read about uniform initialization.

Comment: @mch I just checked the header file, you are right.

Comment: Also read about Vexing parse.

Comment: this isn't really about private. consider clarifying the title

Comment: I agree with @sp2danny the problem really has nothing to do with private. It would be the same if it was in the public section.

Comment: @sp2danny Yes agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your second object in the constructor (or better both):

```
FactorGraph::FactorGraph()
    : _parameters{}, _isam{_parameters}
{ }
```

The initialization happens in the same order in which the members are listed in your class (regardless of the order of this list(!), so it's a good idea to keep the same order here, your compiler may even warn you otherwise), which here guarantees that `_isam` won't get anything uninitialized. (I'm not aware of such guarantees if you just define your objects in your class declaration.)

From the comments, thanks @drescherjm: In your class, just declare your objects **without initializers**:

```
class FactorGraph
{
private:
    gtsam::ISAM2Params _parameters;
    gtsam::ISAM2 _isam;
```

When you declare them without initializers, they should be initialized in the constructor instead. They do not need to be default-constructible in order to do this, the objects gets initialized only once (in the constructor)

Then if you have more constructors, don't forget to either do that everywhere or forward to this one:

```
FactorGraph(int) : FactorGraph{}, /* other initializers */ { }
```

Comment: Cheers, but what should I leave in a private section when declaring the members?

Comment: Also, please be sure to respect the order of declaration, as class members are initialized in their order of declaration, regardless of the order in which you write them out in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks @divinas, I had that in the answer but put more emphasis on it. Also thanks @drescherjm!

Comment: Okay I get it so declaring the objects with a default constructor should work. When initializing, are you redeclaring the object?

Comment: @Edmund No, you're initializing it. It still needs to be declared, before or after this, but without initializer. This replaces the role of in-class `object{...}` and will work (with appropriate parameters to constructors) even if the objects don't allow default initialization, e.g., have default constructors deleted.

Comment: @TheVee Okay I remembered now! The actual initialization comes at the constructor

Comment: @Edmund Declaration, you mean? If so, yes, and it can even appear before, this makes no difference. The initialization, as in, initializing the objects to a sensible state, actually takes place before the body of the constructor, so you can use them in it already.